# SED - char 4: unterminated `s' command

Tags: sed, scripting, printf

I am getting the below error in my script. Can you please help identifying the issue?

```
sed "s/$(printf "\302")/ /g" file1 > file1_new
sed: -e expression #1, char 4: unterminated `s' command
```

But this one is working fine without issues:

```
sed "s/$(printf "\240")/ /g" file1 > file1_new
cat file1_new > file1
rm file1_new
```

What's the problem with the first one?

Comment: Probably less an sed issue but more about escaping: The " of the printf terminates the " of the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears `sed` doesn't play very nicely with binary substitutions.  I did just test what you're doing with `tr` though and it appears to be working.  It's actually pretty easy to do with one command, also:

```
cat /path/to/file1 | tr "$(printf "\302\240")" " " > /path/to/file1_new
```

`tr` is a tool to "translate" the set of characters in its first argument into the set in its second argument (which is extended to match the length of the first set if needed).  So we simply translate each character into a space, as you had been trying to do with `sed`.

Comment: Thank you so much. That worked :-) Really appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

Note that you can access octal/hex numbers directly in `sed` as:

```
sed -e 's/\o302/ /g'  #in octal
sed -e 's/\xC2/ /g'   #in hex
```

Comment: I don't think this is portable to all sed flavors